# How to open files in default program?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, exrin

I'm writing application using Xamarin.forms and i need to open PDF and Doc documents in Droid and IOS. Is there any crossplatform way to achive this? Maybe any packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what type of documents you are taking about. In Xamarin.Forms, you can use

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("filepath or http url"));
```

If there is an application that can handle the extension, then it will prompt you on which app you wish to use.

If you wanted to view them internally, inside the app, without launching a 3rd party app, then we really need to know what type of documents you are opening. If it's a PDF, then you can look at [Display Local PDF File In WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/).

Should it be another type of document, you will need to see if there is a different

Comment: This is not working on `Android` as it causes a `Android.OS.FileUriExposedException`.

Comment: This blog article helped me fixing the Android exception: https://medium.com/p/70b9eb17c6d0

Comment: This is now obsolete.

Answer (score 10):

Now you can use the **Launcher** class by adding a reference to *Xamarin.Essentials* in your class.

For opening a file by another application use:

```
await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(file)
});
```

Where file is the File or FullPath.

You can find more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android